# Why does I/O related setting cause segmentation fault?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, c++17

This is a very weird error and I do not understand why it's happening.

I was practicing SFINAE concepts by writing some generic I/O Reader/Writer implementations. On my local machine, everything works without any segmentation errors. However, when I try testing the same code on [Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/) or some other online compiler sites, I receive `SIGABRT`, `Segmentation fault` error and `Runtime error: exit code is 2147483647` and stuff like that. I ran my code through gdb on my local machine and I don't receive any signals nor segmentation fault. I've made sure than all compilation flags I've used are the same on my local device and the online compilers. I've tested using GCC 9.2.0 and GCC 10.2.0 but in both cases there are problems only on online compilers.

The code I'm testing that gives segmentation fault:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>

namespace io::utility {

    template <typename T, typename = void>
    struct is_istream_streamble
        : std::false_type
    { };

    template <typename T>
    struct is_istream_streamble <T, std::void_t <decltype(std::cin >> std::declval <T&> ())>>
        : std::true_type
    { };

    template <typename T>
    constexpr bool is_istream_streamble_v = is_istream_streamble <T>::value;

    template <typename T, typename = void>
    struct is_ostream_streamble
        : std::false_type
    { };

    template <typename T>
    struct is_ostream_streamble <T, std::void_t <decltype(std::cerr << std::declval <T> ())>>
        : std::true_type
    { };

    template <typename T>
    constexpr bool is_ostream_streamble_v = is_ostream_streamble <T>::value;

    template <typename T, typename = void>
    struct has_begin_iterator
        : std::false_type
    { };

    template <typename T>
    struct has_begin_iterator <T, std::void_t <decltype(std::declval <T> ().begin())>>
        : std::true_type
    { };

    template <typename T>
    constexpr bool has_begin_iterator_v = has_begin_iterator <T>::value;

    template <typename T, typename = void>
    struct has_end_iterator
        : std::false_type
    { };

    template <typename T>
    struct has_end_iterator <T, std::void_t <decltype(std::declval <T> ().end())>>
        : std::true_type
    { };

    template <typename T>
    constexpr bool has_end_iterator_v = has_end_iterator <T>::value;
}

namespace io {

    class reader {
      private:
        std::istream& stream;
      public:
        reader (std::istream& stream = std::cin) : stream (stream) { }

        template <typename T>
        std::enable_if_t <utility::is_ostream_streamble_v <T>, reader&>
        operator () (T& object)
        { return stream >> object, *this; }

        template <typename T>
        std::enable_if_t <!utility::is_ostream_streamble_v <T> && utility::has_begin_iterator_v <T> && utility::has_end_iterator_v <T>, reader&>
        operator () (T& object) {
            for (auto& element : object)
                (*this)(element);
            return *this;
        }

        template <typename A, typename B>
        reader& operator () (std::pair <A, B>& pair)
        { return (*this)(pair.first, pair.second); }

        template <size_t N, typename...T>
        std::enable_if_t <(sizeof...(T) <= N), reader&>
        operator () (std::tuple <T...>&)
        { return *this; }

        template <size_t N, typename...T>
        std::enable_if_t <(sizeof...(T) > N), reader&>
        operator () (std::tuple <T...>& tuple)
        { return (*this)(std::get <N> (tuple)), operator () <N + 1, T...> (tuple); }

        template <typename...T>
        reader& operator () (std::tuple <T...>& tuple)
        { return operator () <0, T...> (tuple); }

        reader& operator () ()
        { return *this; }

        template <typename A, typename...B>
        reader& operator () (A& object, B&...objects)
        { return (*this)(object)(objects...); }
    };

    class writer {
      private:
        std::ostream& stream;
      public:
        writer (std::ostream& stream = std::cerr) : stream (stream) { }

        template <typename T>
        std::enable_if_t <utility::is_ostream_streamble_v <T>, writer&>
        operator () (const T& object)
        { return stream << object, *this; }

        template <typename T>
        std::enable_if_t <!utility::is_ostream_streamble_v <T> && utility::has_begin_iterator_v <T> && utility::has_end_iterator_v <T>, writer&>
        operator () (const T& object) {
            for (const auto& element : object)
                (*this)(element, ' ');
            return *this;
        }

        template <typename A, typename B>
        writer& operator () (const std::pair <A, B>& pair)
        { return (*this)(pair.first, " ", pair.second); }

        template <size_t N, typename...T>
        std::enable_if_t <(sizeof...(T) <= N), writer&>
        operator () (const std::tuple <T...>&)
        { return *this; }

        template <size_t N, typename...T>
        std::enable_if_t <(sizeof...(T) > N), writer&>
        operator () (const std::tuple <T...>& tuple)
        { return (*this)(std::get <N> (tuple), ' '), operator () <N + 1, T...> (tuple); }

        template <typename...T>
        writer& operator () (const std::tuple <T...>& tuple)
        { return operator () <0, T...> (tuple); }

        writer& operator () ()
        { return *this; }

        template <typename A, typename...B>
        writer& operator () (const A& object, const B&...objects)
        { return (*this)(object)(objects...); }
    };
}

using reader = io::reader;
using writer = io::writer;
reader read  (std::cin);
writer write (std::cout);

auto main () -> int32_t {

    std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
    std::cin.tie(nullptr);
    std::cout.precision(10);
    std::cerr.precision(10);
    std::cout << std::fixed << std::boolalpha;
    std::cerr << std::fixed << std::boolalpha;

    int n;
    read(n);
    std::vector <int> a (n);
    read(a);
    write(a);

    return 0;
}
```

Surprisingly, just removing `std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);` makes everything work smoothly without any errors on online compilers. It took me an hour of trying stupid things to figure that out. But I don't understand why that's happening. How does keeping stdio synced solve my problem? An explanation will be highly appreciated.

Comment: What input do you give to your program? What does the debugger show? Please add all the needed  `#include`s - guessing them is no fun. `auto main () -> int32_t ` ? Why `int32_t`?

Comment: @KamilCuk A simple `5 1 2 3 4 5` is the input. The debugger shows what I'd expect it to. `n = 5` and `a = {1 2 3 4 5}`. This is as much I've come to know from local testing and Online GDB. However, wandbox and a few other sites give me RTEs and segmentation fault. Why would `int32_t` cause a problem?

Comment: This `main()` definition looks really bizarre and probably wrong.

Comment: One of the entertaining aspects of undefined behaviour is that making a seemingly unrelated change of code can cause a symptom to disappear.    The problem is very unlikely to be in the `sync_with_stdio(false)` call.   It is likely, however, that removing the call changes the organisation of memory of the program as a whole - and the symptom of the undefined behaviour changes.

Comment: @tadman There is nothing wrong with the main() definition. It is perfectly valid to do so.

Comment: Citation needed on that one. I can't find any [reference to that style](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function). Your return type doesn't match expectations, and I'm not sure what advantage this has over the conventional `int main()` especially considering it's way more verbose. For a moment there I thought this was Rust, but it's C++.

Comment: Could you create an example on wandbox and _post the link to that example_? `There is nothing wrong with the main() definition. It is perfectly valid to do so` It's `int main()`. @edit no matter what I do, I do not get a segfault on my machine, (however running your code without input (with closed input) gives strange result)

Comment: @LostArrow - `main()` is required to return `int`.   `int` is not required to be `int32_t`.

Comment: The `auto main () -> int32_t` is wrong.  The language **requires** it to either be `int main()` or `int main(int argc, char** argv)` (although you can change the parameter names if you desire).

Comment: @KamilCuk With `sync_with_stdio(false)` segmentation fault: [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/sW6GAXz58dDA8Vo0). Without: [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Fg3gMHheEOoEVTu6). There's some bad undefined behaviour in my code i guess if we're getting different results at different places. Also, changed to `int main` in the code linked.

Comment: [super smaller mcve](https://wandbox.org/permlink/gjRsQDkowDbhYX2m). Is defining a variable named `write` at global scope UB? It's funny that just `#include <iostream>
struct W{ W(std::ostream&){} };
W write(std::cout);
int main () {
    std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
    std::cout << "b";
    return 0;
}
` segfaults.

Comment: I'm not surprised anymore. I declared the writer object inside main and no more seg fault. The question is: why?

Comment: `std::cin` and `std::cout` are global **objects** as are your `io` objects. You might be seeing the "static initialization order fiasco" in action since the problem goes away when your objects are moved inside `main()` (no longer global).

Comment: @Blastfurnace You're very likely correct. This morning, I read a little on the same topic and it seems to be the case, I think. If you could compile together an official answer, it'd be great.

Comment: To be honest, I'm not the right person to write a clear and **correct** official answer. I can find related duplicates by searching the phrase on SO but not an exact match to your case. Hopefully one of the C++ language-lawyers can help.

Comment: @KamilCuk theoretically it shouldn't be UB, but in practice your global variables can clash with your entire OS. What can you do about it? Don't use global variables, ever. Not even once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, you have bad luck at naming global variables. This may be the best MCVE I've come up with:

```
#include <iostream>
struct W { W(int) {} };
W write(0);
int main() {
    std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
    std::cout << "b" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

compiling that code with `g++ -O0 -ggdb3 -fsanitize=address ./1.cpp && ./a.out` results in:

```
AddressSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL
=================================================================
==156688==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: SEGV on unknown address 0x5644237db360 (pc 0x5644237db360 bp 0x625000000100 sp 0x7ffd2d2e98b8 T0)
==156688==The signal is caused by a READ memory access.
==156688==Hint: PC is at a non-executable region. Maybe a wild jump?
    #0 0x5644237db360 in write (/tmp/a.out+0x4360)

AddressSanitizer can not provide additional info.
SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: SEGV (/tmp/a.out+0x4360) in write
==156688==ABORTING
```

The [write()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/write.3p.html) and `read()` are standard POSIX functions to communicate with the kernel to do some I/O operations. The `write` symbol you defined *is not mangled* and it *overwrites* the standard `write` function provided from glibc. When `std::ios::sync_with_stdio` is called, that makes `libstdc++` call `write` syscall, but linker resolves that symbol *not* to the `write` symbol defined inside glibc library, but to the definition of your symbol inside your file.

```
$ gdb ./a.out
[...]
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000555555558a60 in write ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0000555555558a60 in write ()
#1  0x00007ffff749c49f in (anonymous namespace)::xwrite (__n=2, __s=0x625000000100 "b\n", '\276' <repeats 198 times>..., __fd=1) at basic_file.cc:120
#2  std::__basic_file<char>::xsputn (this=this@entry=0x7ffff75b0c08 <__gnu_internal::buf_cout+104>, 
    __s=__s@entry=0x625000000100 "b\n", '\276' <repeats 198 times>..., __n=__n@entry=2) at basic_file.cc:325
#3  0x00007ffff74dd025 in std::basic_filebuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >::_M_convert_to_external (
    this=this@entry=0x7ffff75b0ba0 <__gnu_internal::buf_cout>, __ibuf=0x625000000100 "b\n", '\276' <repeats 198 times>..., __ilen=2)
    at /build/gcc/src/gcc-build/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/fstream.tcc:642
#4  0x00007ffff74dd46f in std::basic_filebuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >::overflow (this=0x7ffff75b0ba0 <__gnu_internal::buf_cout>, __c=-1)
    at /build/gcc/src/gcc-build/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/streambuf:536
#5  0x00007ffff74db1ad in std::basic_filebuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >::sync (this=<optimized out>)
    at /build/gcc/src/gcc-build/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/fstream.tcc:1020
#6  std::basic_filebuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >::sync (this=<optimized out>)
    at /build/gcc/src/gcc-build/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/fstream.tcc:1012
#7  0x00007ffff7503d83 in std::basic_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >::pubsync (this=<optimized out>)
    at /build/gcc/src/gcc-build/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/streambuf:278
#8  std::ostream::flush (this=0x555555558900 <std::cout@@GLIBCXX_3.4>)
    at /build/gcc/src/gcc-build/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/ostream.tcc:219
#9  0x000055555555532f in main () at ./1.cpp:8
(gdb) pt &write
type = struct W {
  public:
    W(int);
} *
(gdb) p &write
$2 = (W *) 0x555555558a60 <write>
(gdb) p &__libc_write
$3 = (<text variable, no debug info> *) 0x7ffff671df20 <write>
```

As of now, I do not understand why `write` is not mangled (shouldn't it be?). The simplest solution is to keep your global variables within a namespace:

```
namespace my {
    W write(0);
}
// results in:
// $ nm ./a.out | grep write
// 0000000000004191 B _ZN2my5writeE  - OK!
```

Or add a `static` in front of `write` and `read` variable declarations. Or pick another names, different from ones provided from POSIX. Or move variable declarations to inside `int main()` function.

Comment: `write` is not a function. Only functions names are mangled. Variable names are not (you can't overload a variable).